# Date operation insede and array (aggreagation)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to build online test application using mongoDB and nodeJS. And there is a feature which admin can view user test history (with date filter option).

How to do the query, if I want to display only user which the test results array contains date specified by admin.

The date filter will be based on day, month, year from scheduledAt.startTime, and I think I must use aggregate framework to achieve this.

Let's say I have users document like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582a7b315c57b9164cac3295"),
    "username" : "lalalala@gmail.com",
    "displayName" : "lalala",
    "testResults" : [ 
        {
            "applyAs" : [ 
                "finance"
            ],
            "scheduledAt" : {
                "endTime" : ISODate("2016-11-15T16:00:00.000Z"),
                "startTime" : ISODate("2016-11-15T01:00:00.000Z")
            },
            "results" : [ 
                ObjectId("582a7b3e5c57b9164cac3299"), 
                ObjectId("582a7cc25c57b9164cac329d")
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("582a7b3e5c57b9164cac3296")
        },
        { 
           ..... 
        }
    ],
    "password" : "andi",
}
```

testResults document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582a7cc25c57b9164cac329d"),
    "testCategory" : "english",
    "testVersion" : "EAX",
    "testTakenTime" : ISODate("2016-11-15T03:10:58.623Z"),
    "score" : 2,
    "userAnswer" : [ 
        {
            "answer" : 1,
            "problemId" : ObjectId("581ff74002bb1218f87f3fab")
        }, 
        {
            "answer" : 0,
            "problemId" : ObjectId("581ff78202bb1218f87f3fac")
        }, 
        {
            "answer" : 0,
            "problemId" : ObjectId("581ff7ca02bb1218f87f3fad")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

What I have tried until now is like below. If I want to count total document, which part of my aggregation framework should I change. Because in query below, totalData is being summed per group not per whole returned document.

```
User
      .aggregate([
        {
          $unwind: '$testResults'
        },
        {
          $project: {
            '_id': 1,
            'displayName': 1,
            'testResults': 1,
            'dayOfTest': { $dayOfMonth: '$testResults.scheduledAt.startTime' },
            'monthOfTest': { $month: '$testResults.scheduledAt.startTime' },
            'yearOfTest': { $year: '$testResults.scheduledAt.startTime' }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            dayOfTest: date.getDate(),
            monthOfTest: date.getMonth() + 1,
            yearOfTest: date.getFullYear()
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {id: '$_id', displayName: '$displayName'},
            testResults: {
              $push: '$testResults'
            },
            totalData: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
      ])
      .then(function(result) {
        res.send(result);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        next(err);
      });
```

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @Veeram Hi, I already update my explaination. Please check it :)

Comment: you can add another group stage.  Group by null which will get you the total count across all user documents and push the display, group count and test results from previous group and you can add a optional final project stage to format your response. You can add your expected response in case this doesnt work and i can try.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but I think the result still not like my expectation.
Here is result comparison: [link](http://pastebin.com/13xU3TgE).  Here is my code: [link](http://pastebin.com/yzSZcMJH). I put my code in pastebin, because if I put here, it will be too long :)

Comment: Can you replace the last group stage with this code ? {
  $group: {
 _id: null,
   testResults: {
  $push: {
    _id: '$_id',
   testResults: '$testResults'
  },
    totalData: {
   $sum: 1
    }
   }
  }
}

Comment: @Veeram Thanks mate, it works perfectly (y). But honestly, the result which I really really expected is little bit different from that i said before.

Is it possible to include all the testResults array from one person, if the one element of the testResults array match certain condition.

Comment: Based on aggregation pipeline that we construct I think it is not possible, because it will filtered the testResults. Any suggestion to achieve that?

Comment: yeah we can do that. what is the condition that you want ? we can add a match/ project stage. We can add an elemmatch with project. Give me an example.

Comment: Lets say I have two documents like this: [link](http://pastebin.com/SuNDNUHt).
I want filter based on date-month-year (15-11-2016).

The results I expected is pretty much like before, except I don't want to filter out the testResults. as long as one element of their testResults array match the filter condition.

Comment: here is my expected results from document above: [link](http://pastebin.com/tfM0j6X1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Added the project stage to keep the test results if any of result element matches on the date passed. Add this as the first step in the pipeline and you can add the grouping stage the way you want.

$map applies an equals comparison between the date passed and start date in each test result element and generates an array with true and false values. $anyElementTrue inspects this array and returns true only if there is atleast one true value in the array. Match stage to include only elements with matched value of true.

```
aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "displayName":1,
        "testResults": 1,
        "matched": {
            "$anyElementTrue": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$testResults",
                    "as": "result",
                    "in": {
                        "$eq": [{ $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: '$$result.scheduledAt.startTime' } }, '2016-11-15']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "matched": true
    }
}])
```

Alternative Version:

Similar to the above version but this one combines both the project and match stage into one. The $cond with $redact accounts for match and when match is found it keeps the complete tree or else discards it.

```
aggregate([{
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [{
                "$anyElementTrue": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$testResults",
                        "as": "result",
                        "in": {
                            "$eq": [{
                                $dateToString: {
                                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                                    date: '$$result.scheduledAt.startTime'
                                }
                            }, '2016-11-15']
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }
}])
```

Comment: Cool man, I think this answer work perfectly. Maybe I will learn your answer first, because in your solution there are many strange syntax or operator which I still don't know.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have just added an alternative version and also added description of what each operator is doing. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, please don't say sorry Veeram. I don't mean like that. I mean, I will learn your answer first because I'm still new in mongoDB, therefore many syntax seems strange to me.

Your solution is really helping me to know the implementation of a lot of features which are included in mongoDB docs. It's really helping me when I read the docs, because I know the real implementation and the results of each features / operator.

Btw thanks for the alternative version, its really help me to learn mongoDB deeper.